# How to delete the instance of the button from UI view in javafx

Tags: button, javafx

I have a button in the java fx which is present in HBox of the UI and I want to delete that Button on clicking the same button.i have written the action event for the same:

```
@FXML
private HBOx projectlist;
String buttonid;
```

String buttoname;
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
   @FXML
   public  Button delete;

```
button.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            buttonid= button.getId();
            buttoname = button.getText();
            projectlist.getChildren().remove(buttoname);
        }
    });
```

Actually the problem is I am getting the button from other controller in this function and i am not able to use that button in another button(Delete) action event although i am able to use buttonid variable in delete action event:                                                                                                        public  void setButton(Button button,String buttonname) {

```
projectlist.setSpacing(10);

button.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        buttonid= button.getId();
        buttoname = button.getText();


    }
});
```

projectlist.getChildren().add(button);

```
}                                                                                                  @FXML
private void gotoDelete(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
     ProjectModule.DeleteProject(Integer.parseInt(buttonid));

projectlist.getChildren().remove(button);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
button.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        buttonid= button.getId();
        buttoname = button.getText();

        projectList.getChildren().remove(button);

    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the edits. Can you fix the formatting and generally make it clearer? You just need to call `projectList.getChildren().remove(button);` in the button's handler method. (As an aside, you should really use `setOnAction`, not `setOnMouseClicked`.)

Comment: Thanks james......Actually i found the solution for it .....may be not the best approach but still works for me.........