# Remove a button by clicking on it in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

I am building a calander/planner application using JavaFX. The app consists of a single GridPane with 35 (7x5) VBox's. Within these VBox's are TaskButtons (implemented below). When I right click a TaskBox it will turn the text to grey and when I left click the TsskButton I want it to delete the button. Things I know already.

1. AnchorPaneNode (extends VBox) doesn't have a static getChildren() method.
2. I cannot create a separate instance variable for pane since I will not know how many I will have.
3. getParent().getChildren() doesn't work because the parents method of getChildren() is not visible.
4. VBox has a public getChildren(), but it is not static.
5. I tried to make a static accessor to getChildren(), but was unable to.

What else can I try to get this button removed when right clicking? Thank you for your help!

```
public class TaskButton extends Button {

    protected int buttonNum = AnchorPaneNode.listIndex;
    public TaskButton(String str)
    {
        super(str);

        setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");


        setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) 
            {
                //I want to remove this button from the VBox, neither of these work
                AnchorPaneNode.getChildren().remove(this);
                //or
                getParent().getChildren().remove(this);
            }
            else if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) 
            {
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-text-fill: #666666;");
            }           
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it will be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722232/how-to-delete-the-instance-of-the-button-from-ui-view-in-javafx

Comment: @KumarAnilChaurasiya I already saw this thread and unfortunately it wasn't helpful. This solution had a set instance variable for the VBox which I would like to avoid at all costs since I would most likely have hundreds if not thousands of VBox's in my application. Thank you for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer to my own question!
For those that run into the same issue this is what I did to solve it:

```
setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
        //I want to remove this button from the VBox, neither of these work
        //AnchorPaneNode.getChildren().remove(this);
        //or
        VBox vbox = (VBox) getParent();
        vbox.getChildren().remove(this);
    } else if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
        setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-text-fill: #666666;");
    }           
});
```

I needed to access the public getChildren() that VBox provides and I did so by casting (this)getParent() to a VBox. From there I was able to getChildren() and remove "this".